# How to get individual dict from a nested dict?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Having following json file

```
{
  "front_page": {
    "institue": {
      "inst_name": "University Name",
      "size": 12,
      "type": "bold"
    },
    "doc_type": {
      "name": "(Scope Document)",
      "size": 12,
      "type": "bold"
    },
    "project_title": {
      "name": "Project Title",
      "size": 12,
      "type": "bold"
    },
    "Version": {
      "Version": "Version 1.0",
      "size": 12,
      "type": "bold"
    },
    "Degree": {
      "name": "Becholar of Science in Computer Science(2016-2020)",
      "size": 12,
      "type": "bold"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get all nested dictionaries as separate dict object.
So far I only managed to get all key, value pairs

```
def parse_json_obj(json_obj):
    for k, v in json_obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print('found at ', k)
            parse_json_obj(v)
        else:
            print(v)
```

what I'm trying to do is get each dict and append its content to a pdf page. I've already figured out how to handle each dict for pdf but don't know how to extract dictionaries.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you mean here. you are recursively going through doing just what you state. You check if v is a dict. If it is then v is that individual dict. So what is it you want to do with v?

Comment: can you post your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming if what you want is all the dicts which dont have sub dicts in them you could do the following.

```py
jdict = {
    "front_page": {
        "institue": {
            "inst_name": "University Name",
            "size": 12,
            "type": "bold"
        },
        "doc_type": {
            "name": "(Scope Document)",
            "size": 12,
            "type": "bold"
        },
        "project_title": {
            "name": "Project Title",
            "size": 12,
            "type": "bold"
        },
        "Version": {
            "Version": "Version 1.0",
            "size": 12,
            "type": "bold"
        },
        "Degree": {
            "name": "Becholar of Science in Computer Science(2016-2020)",
            "size": 12,
            "type": "bold"
        }
    }
}


def parse_json_obj(json_obj):
    list_of_dicts = []
    for item in json_obj.values():
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            has_sub_dict = [subdict for subdict in item.values() if isinstance(subdict, dict)]
            if has_sub_dict:
                list_of_dicts += parse_json_obj(item)
            else:
                list_of_dicts.append(item)
    return list_of_dicts

list_of_dicts = parse_json_obj(jdict)
print(*list_of_dicts, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'inst_name': 'University Name', 'size': 12, 'type': 'bold'}
{'name': '(Scope Document)', 'size': 12, 'type': 'bold'}
{'name': 'Project Title', 'size': 12, 'type': 'bold'}
{'Version': 'Version 1.0', 'size': 12, 'type': 'bold'}
{'name': 'Becholar of Science in Computer Science(2016-2020)', 'size': 12, 'type': 'bold'}
```

If this isnt what you were trying to achieve then i would suggest to update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks exactly what I was looking for. You saved the day